# I have to integrate custom error handling in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have to create one service that will log any run-time error occurred in the application.

I have created a service named "ErrorHandlingService" and below given code is written

```
 import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
 export class ErrorhandlingService implements ErrorHandler {
     handleError(error: any): void {
         console.error('Some error occured: ', error);
     }
 }
```

In app.module.ts I have written the below code

```
 @NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent],
     entryComponents: [],
     providers: [StatusBar, SplashScreen,
         { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
         { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorhandlingService },
     bootstrap: [AppComponent],
 })
```

But still the default error is shown

Comment: you seem to have missed setting it as a service `@Injectable()`

Comment: I have got with the solution. I have just updated my code
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorhandlingService implements ErrorHandler {

Answer (score 0):

How did you test that default error is being shown?

I tried with the same code you have written and it is working fine.
Try testing by using,

`throw new Error('error string')`

Here's stackblitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yashpatelyk-random

Note : You don't need `@Injectable()` which is suggested in one comment since you are providing the class in the `useClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated by error handling code to below:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorhandlingService implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any): void {
        const Dt = new Date().toISOString();
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log(Dt, '\r\nHTTP error: ', error.message, '\r\nStatus code:', (<HttpErrorResponse>error).status);
        }
        else if (error instanceof TypeError) {
            console.log(Dt, '\r\nType Error: ', error.message);
        }
        else if (error instanceof Error) {
            console.log(Dt, '\r\nGeneral Error: ', error.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log(Dt, '\r\nAnonymous Error: ', error);
        }
    }
}
```